# Using C#, how do I determine if an uploaded file has any accessible metadata/document properties?

Tags: c#, metadata, ms-office, document, openoffice.org

Suppose I have a program which allows a user to upload any kind of file.  Along with getting generic information such as file type and file size, I would like to attempt to grab any extra information (such as document properties like author, last revised, etc) that may be transported along with the document.

Since I don't have any knowledge about the incoming document/file ahead of time, I can't simply use classes that are specific to, say Microsoft Office docs.  I need to do this generically and then construct a dynamic object or dictionary to hold any found key/value results.

Is this possible?  If so, how?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found a few answers on StackOverflow for this, but none gave me a nice, clean dictionary of document properties.  Here is what I finally came up with and it seems to be working nicely (you will need to reference "Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation" from the COM folder and add `using Shell32;` to your code:

```
 public static Dictionary<string,string> GetDocumentMetadata(string fileName)
        {
            var properties = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            var arrHeaders = new List<string>();

            var shell = new Shell();
            var objFolder = shell.NameSpace(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/RawFiles"));
            var file = objFolder.ParseName(fileName);

            for (var i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
            {
                var header = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(null, i);
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(header))
                    break;
                arrHeaders.Add(header);
            }

            for (var i = 0; i < arrHeaders.Count; i++)
            {
                var value = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(file, i);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    properties.Add(arrHeaders[i], value);
                }
            }

            return properties;
        }
```